# How to unit test a POST method in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, post

I have a method that sends a POST containing a JSON to an Elasticsearch instance. I am trying to write a unit test that verify the contents of the sent JSON, but I am not sure how to go about that. Should I create a local server in python and have it verify the contents of the POST or something else? I currently have this:

```
class TestAnalytics(BaseTest):

    def test_post(self):
        info = {"test1": "value1", "test2": "value2"}
        resp = requests.post(config.tool_repo_urls['es_url'], data=json.dumps(info), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        assert_equal(resp.status_code, 200)  # verify valid response code
```

Comment: Create a unit test to POST and check the result of the POST based on the returned value from the API and then run a GET to confirm the contents match what you POSTed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Creating a local server would be an overkill, what you can do is use unitest library to patch the `post()` method so it sends the data to your internal assertion method using patch method here  is the link https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html. You should look at  section **27.6.2. Patch Decorators**

Example:

```
class TestAnalytics(BaseTest):

    @patch('requests.post')
    def test_post(self,mock_post):
        info = {"test1": "value1", "test2": "value2"}
        resp = requests.post(config.tool_repo_urls['es_url'], data=json.dumps(info), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        #Some checks done on mock_post object
```

Full working example below
**EDIT:**

```
import json

from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

import requests


class TestAnalytics(TestCase):

    @patch('requests.post')
    def test_post(self, mock_post):
        info = {"test1": "value1", "test2": "value2"}
        resp = requests.post("www.someurl.com", data=json.dumps(info), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        mock_post.assert_called_with("www.someurl.com", data=json.dumps(info), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})


TestAnalytics().test_post()
```

Method `assert_called_with` checks if the patched method was called exactly with the parameters specified in its invocation. In this case it is True

Changing it to for example:

```
mock_post.assert_called_with("www.someurl.com", data=json.dumps(info))
```

Will give:

```
AssertionError: Expected call: post('www.someurl.com', data='{"test1": "value1", "test2": "value2"}')
Actual call: post('www.someurl.com', data='{"test1": "value1", "test2": "value2"}', headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

You can also use the `mock_post` object to check indvidiual parametrs please check the link above for the full specs of what `MagicMock` can do

**EDIT2**

Recently found out about this little library for unit testing `requests`

https://github.com/getsentry/responses

Comment: Could you clarify that commented out line? I'm not sure what you mean with `mock.assert_called_with, your_Expected_value`

Comment: How can i mock the url to avoid sending the request to the actual URL?

Comment: @technazi I am not sure if I understand your question the example I have presented mocks all outgoing traffic. Would you like to allow some URL and others not?

Comment: @CodeSamurai777 Thanks for the reply. I was wodnering what if there is a POST URL which you can't test - like it would affect the data or something and we can not actually call the URL instead mock the URL and see if thee data  sent is correct regardless of the URL.

Comment: @technazi The above example does just that this`@patch('requests.post')` creates a MagicMock for the post method `.assert_called_with` checks what arguments where passed to MagicMock for `post` method url, params etc. Please upvote it if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify the sent JSON you should try `json.loads()`, which will throw a ValueError if the input you pass can't be decoded as JSON.